# Como desconsiderar parcialmente NA em operações no R com uma série histórica de dados?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Possuo um conjunto de dados de chuva medidos a cada hora e preciso somar esses dados ao longo do dia. Para isso, estou utilizando os comandos abaixo:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(data) %>%
summarise_all(funs(Media=sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Porém, meu df apresenta três características: i) dias sem NA, ii) dias com alguns NAs, e iii) dias apenas com NA, conforme exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso, se eu considerar `na.rm=TRUE`, os dias que possuem apenas NA, como o dia 03/01/10, retorna com um valor 0 após a soma. O que está errado, pois não sei se não choveu mesmo, uma vez que não tenho o dado. Pelo contrário, `na.rm=FALSE`, desconsidero tanto os dias que possuem apenas NA quanto os dias que possuem alguns NAs e algumas medidas, o que também é ruim.

Na saída apresentada abaixo, o dia 02/01/2010 deveria apresentar um valor diferente de 0.0 e o dia 03/01/2010 deveria apresentar NA. Quando calculo a média `Media=mean` o resultado é correto, porém para `Media=sum` não consigo corrigir isso.

```
data    "rain_mm_ToT"
01/01/2010  19.7
02/01/2010  0.0
03/01/2010  0.0
04/01/2010  0.5
05/01/2010  0.0
06/01/2010  0.0
07/01/2010  6.3
08/01/2010  1.9
09/01/2010  1.4
10/01/2010  0.0
11/01/2010  0.0
```

Como a série é muito longa, não consigo fazer uma avaliação minunciosa de onde estarão os erros. Desse modo, gostaria de saber se existe uma alternativa para considerar "parcialmente" os valores NAs, isto é, retornar com NA apenas nos dias que não apresentam nenhuma medição e realizar a soma naqueles que possuem tanto NA quanto medição?

Obrigada!

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(df)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(df, 20))`?

Answer (score 3):

Esta resposta trata os casos em que pelo menos um elemento do vetor cuja média deve ser calculada é `NA` com `na.rm = TRUE`. Mas ao contrário do que está escrito na pergunta, quando todos os elementos são `NA` o valor da média é `NaN`, não é `0`. Isto faz sentido uma vez que se removermos todos os dados temos a soma de zero elementos dividida por zero, o comprimento desse vetor de zero elementos. Ora `0/0` dá `NaN`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(data) %>%
  summarise_all(list(Media = ~mean(., na.rm = anyNA(.))))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#   data  Media
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1     1   2.5 
#2     2   2.33
#3     3 NaN
```

Esta segunda forma de calcular as médias por grupos tendo em conta os valores em falta, `NA`, considera o caso de todos os valores serem `NA` à parte e tem como resultado `NA`. Mas pelo motivo explicado acima creio que o primeiro código é o mais correto.

```
df %>%
  group_by(data) %>%
  summarise_all(list(Media = ~mean(., na.rm = !all(is.na(.)))))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#   data Media
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1  2.5 
#2     2  2.33
#3     3 NA
```

**Dados de teste.**

```
df <- data.frame(data = rep(1:3, each = 4),
                 `chuva(mm)` = c(1:4, c(1,2,NA,4), rep(NA, 4)))
```

Comment: Obrigada pelo comentário! Quando calculo valores médios de chuva para o dia o resultado não apresenta problemas (Media =~mean). Porém, quando preciso dos valores acumulados ao longo do dia (Media=sum) é que tenho dificuldades. Pois a função retorna com 0.0 tando onde tenho apenas NA quanto nos dias em que tenho algumas medições e alguns NAs.